# Select element from a list inside an iframe using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I would like to write a python Programm which downloads automaticaly historical stock data from a web-page. The correspindent HTML-Code of the Element I would like to select is on the following Picture:

There are two iframes. One is inside the other. I switch to the second iframe, but the element I would like to click can't be found. I get the following error: "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id=":cu"]"}   (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)"

```py
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.   
import time

user = ""
pwd = ""
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.dukascopy.com/trading-tools/widgets/quotes/historical_data_feed")
driver.maximize_window()

## Give time for iframe to load ##
time.sleep(1)

# get the list of iframes present on the web page using tag "iframe"
seq = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print("No of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))

#switch to correct iFrame
driver.switch_to_default_content()
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[1]
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id(':cu')
elem.click()

ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Test", "Test MsgBox", 1)

driver.close()
```

If my code would be correct the element "EUR/TRY" in the List would be selected.

Comment: It should print `print("No of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))` 4 ?

Comment: anyway what do you want to extract from page ?

Comment: I would like to download historical stock data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are total 4 iframes.

The table you want to interact with is in `iframe[src^='https://freeserv']` and parent iframe is `widget-container`. One by one you have to switch to it like this :

**Code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.dukascopy.com/trading-tools/widgets/quotes/historical_data_feed")

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "widget-container")))

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src^='https://freeserv']")))

check_Box = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='EUR/TRY']/../preceding-sibling::span/span")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(check_Box).perform()
check_Box.click()
```